# Electric dipole potential distance from charge distribution

Tags: charge, potential, dipole-moment

For the dipole term of electric potential, the potential value a distance away can be calculated, assuming that the distance of the potential "probe" is much greater than the distance between charges.

I am modeling a dipole, and I want to calculate the potential from the dipole a distance away, but I am not sure how far away to put the probe. Is there a way that I can determine how far away the probe needs to be to accurately give me the potential from the dipole?

Comment: The potential depends on the angle of the position vector with respect to the dipole moment vector as well as the distance. And are you wanting to use the distance approximation $\phi(r) \propto r^{-2}$, or do an exact calculation?

Comment: I am doing an exact calculation based on the angle and the direction of the dipole with respect to the point where the voltage is recorded.

Comment: Because you aren't making an approximation, any distance that doesn't put you on a charge is okay. If you were making the approximation, I would suggest at least 10X the charge separation distance, $d$.  In fact, you may want to chose several distances from the center of the dipole, e.g. d, 3d, 8d, 12d, 20d, and see how the strength changes.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion - I will try that!